# Comparing two un-ordered lists for differences in individual elements

Tags: python

Given two lists:

```
listA = ['A' , 'B' , 'C, D' , 'E, F, G', 'H' , 'I']

listB = ['C' , 'E, G' , 'A' , 'B' , 'I']
```

I want to compare each element and highlight the differences where it is applicable.

```
listA['E,F,G'] and listB['E,G'].

The difference would be ['F']
```

There are several differences between the individual list elements and ideally would like to flag them all. Is this possible with python? Is the below thinking correct?

```
set(listA).intersection(listB)
```

Comment: What should the output be if the input is `["A", "B"]` and `["C", "B"]`? What should the output be if the input is `["D"]` and `["D", "D", "D", "D", "D"]`?

Comment: @Kevin In the first case, the output would be ['A' , 'C'] and in the second case that would be considered OK.

Comment: "OK" as in, the output would be "there is no difference"? OK. I was curious whether the number of occurrences was a factor.

Comment: What's up with those "nested" string-pseudo-lists? Should those be unpacked, or compared as-is? What would be the difference for your first two lists?

Comment: @Kevin OK as in 'there is no difference' sorry.

Comment: @tobias_k I would like to try and compare them 'as is'

Comment: So, the difference between `["a, b, c"]` and `["a, c"]` is `{"a, b, c", "a, c"}`, and not `{"b"}`, right?

Comment: @tobias_k The difference between  ["a, b, c"]  and ["a, c"] would be {"b"}

Comment: @MaxB so you don't want to compare them 'as is', but want to unpack them first to be individual elements...

Comment: @ruohola honestly I am having trouble explaining it. The difference between ["a, b, c"] and ["a, c"] would be {"b"}

Comment: Oh I see you have a 'e, f, g' string. That was hard to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments, it seems like you want to "unpack" the nested pseudo-string-lists before calculating the difference. You could define a simple helper function for that.

```
>>> listA = ['A' , 'B' , 'C, D' , 'E, F, G', 'H' , 'I']
>>> listB = ['C' , 'E, G' , 'A' , 'B' , 'I']
>>> elements = lambda s: set(x for y in s for x in y.split(", "))
>>> elements(listA)
{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'}
```

Then, you can use `set` operations like `-`, `^`, `&`, or `|` to get what you want.

```
>>> elements(listA) - elements(listB) # difference
{'D', 'F', 'H'}
>>> elements(listA) ^ elements(listB) # sym. diff.
{'D', 'F', 'H'}
>>> elements(listA) & elements(listB) # intersection
{'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'}
>>> elements(listA) | elements(listB) # union
{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is symmetric difference. In python you can achieve it by using `symmetric_difference` function or using short hand `s ^ t`.

`s.symmetric_difference(t)`

---

This will give you the difference elements. Now, what you can do is

```
def split_words(element):
   if len(element) > 1:
      element = element.split(',')
   return element

result = []
for e1, e2 in zip(sorted(list_a), sorted(list_b)):
    if e1 not in list_b:
       e1 = split_words(e1)
       e2 = split_words(e2)

       diff = set(e1) ^ set(e2)
       result.append(diff)
```

Comment: Not sure about this sorting-and-zipping thing... what if the lists have different lengths? Also, your `split_words` methods will sometimes return a list, and other times a string, meaning that when you turn `e1` and `e2` into `set`, you can come out with either a set of words, or a set of characters.

Comment: @tobias_k In case of different length list, how would we know which list contains the true values?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but the lists in OP's first example _have_ different length, so this seems to be a valid case.

Comment: @tobias_k Yea it's a valid case.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection is a common part of sets. If you want a difference of sets just use... a difference method. 
E.g.:

```
list(set(listA) - set(listB))
```

or:

```
list(set(listA).difference(set(listB)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listA = ['E','F','G']
listB = ['E','G']
```

use list comprehension

```
diff2 = [y for y in listA if y not in listB]
print (diff2)
```

output: ['F']

or

```
diff1=[]
for item in listA:
    if item not in listB:
        diff1.append(item)
print (diff1)
```

output: ['F']